# OpenAPI: Best approach for scaling a strongly-typed API suite

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I have the same object that needs to be used across multiple SDKs.

Say the yaml file for `ServiceA` contains `Object1` and I want to use it in the `ServiceB` yaml file.

In the `ServiceB` file I easily reference `Object1` with `$ref: ./service-a.yaml#/components/schemas/Object1`, however when generating the SDKs for each service separately there are two different objects. (This is expected.)

1. `com.example.sdk.serviceA.models.Object1`
2. `com.example.sdk.serviceB.models.Object1`

When using this in an application where `serviceA` calls `serviceB` I can't pass `serviceA.models.Object1` into the `serviceB` API because it will throw a type error. It is expecting `serviceB.models.Object1`.

To solve for this I know of two approaches:

1. Create extension functions to convert `serviceA.models.Object1` to `serviceB.models.Object1`. This doesn't scale nicely if one has many reusable objects across many services.
2. Import all the paths into a single file and just generate the main file. This scales but there are two concerns.

   i. When importing the SDK into an application I am importing all APIs (over 300+), as a result the import is a lot larger then it should to be.

   ii. I have to create two paths for each API, one in the service file and one in the main file.

Question: Is there a more appropriate way to solve for this?

Comment: Since you use `openapi-generator`, check out its options for [Type Mapping](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage/#type-mappings-and-import-mappings) and  [External Models](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage/#target-external-models).

Comment: What @Helen said. And you can easily let `$ref` inside ServiceA and ServiceB point to a 3rd openapi file which only holds the model declaration. This will be dereferenced for you (= `$ref` will be replaced with the schema from the 3rd file)

Comment: What @Helen mentioned is the correct approach as per how OpenAPI incorporates external models. This means that every object has to be mapped into the command. This is how the generator is aware of the external object.  However, at scale this would be very error prone if done manually and very difficult to automate in a script. But this does give clarity on how OpenAPI solves for this. Thank you Helen.